# Need to build docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile.  When building, it returns the following error:

> The command '/bin/sh -c CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .' returned a non-zero code: 1

Below is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Comment: CMD ["./app.go"] ?

Comment: I don't know GO language, but this clause : RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app . Does not run properly (i'm guessing that is your build) Do this: docker run -it --rm -v <PATH_TO_YOUR_CODE>:/go/src golang:1.7.3 bash 

cd to /go/src and launch your command: CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app . It should spit out log to stdout and you will know what is wrong. When done type : exit or ctrl+d to exit the container (it will be remove after you do so because of the --rm flag)

Comment: That error amounts to "the program didn't build"; the actual interesting error is going to be before that.  Without knowing what's in `app.go` it's hard to say what actually went wrong.

Comment: on more thing you are changing workdir between copy and cmd i suggest not using relative paths